# Monstrous Moonshine for Thompson group $Th$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, modular-forms

**I.** As a background, in *[Traces of Singular Moduli](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/tex/TracesSingModuli/fulltext.pdf)* (p.2), Zagier defines the modular form of weight 3/2,

$$g(\tau) = \frac{\eta^2(\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)}\frac{E_4(4\tau)}{\eta^6(4\tau)}=\vartheta_4(\tau)\, \eta^2(4\tau)\,\sqrt[3]{j(4\tau)}$$

which has the nice *q*-expansion ([A027652](http://oeis.org/A027652), negated terms),

$$g(\tau) = 1/q - 2 + 248q^3 - 492q^4 +(15^3+744)q^7 + \dots + (5280^3+744)q^{67} + \dots + (640320^3+744)q^{163}+\dots$$

However, one can use other Eisenstein series $E_k(\tau)$ as the one below.

**II.** In a [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404427v1.pdf) by Bruinier (p.6), Borcherds defines a modular form of weight 1/2. First let,

$$K(\tau) = \tfrac{1}{16}\big(\vartheta_3^4(\tau) - \tfrac{1}{8}\vartheta_2^4(\tau)\big)\,\vartheta_2^4(\tau)\vartheta_3(\tau)\vartheta_4^4(\tau)$$

then,

$$b(\tau) = 60\vartheta_3(\tau)+\frac{K(\tau)E_6(4\tau)}{\eta^{24}(4\tau)} = 60\vartheta_3(\tau)+\frac{K(\tau)\sqrt{j(4\tau)-1728}}{\eta^{12}(4\tau)} $$

This has the *q*-expansion ([A013953](http://oeis.org/A013953)),

$$b(\tau) = 1/q^3 + 4 - 240q + (\color{blue}{27000}-240)q^4 - \color{blue}{85995}q^5 + \color{blue}{1707264}q^8 - (\color{blue}{4096000}+240)q^9 + \color{blue}{44330496}q^{12}-91951146q^{13}+\dots$$

I noticed that the blue numbers appear in the degrees of irreducible representations of the **Thompson group** $Th$, given by the finite sequence of 48 integers ([A003916](http://oeis.org/A003916)),

$$1, 248, 4123, \color{blue}{27000}, 30628, 30875, 61256, \color{blue}{85995},  147250, 767637, 779247, 957125, \color{blue}{1707264}, 2450240, 2572752, 3376737, \color{blue}{4096000}, 4123000, 4881384, 4936750,\dots\color{blue}{44330496},\dots 91171899, 111321000, 190373976.$$

with repeated terms deleted for brevity.

***Questions***:

1. If it is not coincidence, what is the reason?
2. In Bruinier (p.6) he says one can use $E_k(\tau)$ for $k=4,6,8,10,14$. What are the other functions for higher $k$?

***Edit***: As pointed out by S. Carnahan below, there is already a known moonshine for $Th$. A partial(?) list of others from Griess' *"Happy Family"* can be found in [Monstrous Moonshine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine#Generalized_Moonshine), such as for the Higman-Sims $HS$ and so on. (Are there more?)

Comment: One also has 91951146 = 779247 + 91171899.

Comment: Ah, missed that! I added more terms to include 91171899. Thanks.

Comment: The next coefficient 708938760 seems to be harder to decompose..

Comment: Based on the original moonshine, I think sums of small multiples of the terms are allowed.

Comment: 708938760=190373976+3*111321000+2*91171899+1707264+6*85995+30628+4123+1.

Comment: Aren't you tempted to get rid of the annoying factors of 240 by adding $120 \vartheta(0,\tau)$?

Comment: I'm sure Borcherds has a reason why it is defined that way. Do you know the functions that use $E_k$ for $k = 10,14$?

Comment: Not right off hand, but will take a look.

Comment: Hum, maybe there is also a 240 in the coefficient 708938760, as it is the coefficient of $q^{16}$ ?

Comment: Probably, as 708938760+240 =190373976+3*91171899+44330496+2*3376737+2572752+957125+61256+248 which has lower multiplicities than needed without adding 240.

Comment: The Thompson group is a subgroup of the Chevalley group $E_8(3)$ and the Eisenstein series $E_4$, which is equal to the $E_8$ theta function is the Borcherds lift of the weight $1/2$ modular form you wrote down. Perhaps this is a starting point for trying to understand the connection between Thompson irreps and $b(\tau)$.

Comment: There are a few words at the end of section 4 of Borcherds' article "Modular Moonshine II" (http://math.berkeley.edu/~reb/papers/modular2/modular2.pdf) about $E_8(3)$ and the Thompson group. But this concerns modular representations of Th.

Comment: @F.C. The modular moonshine puzzle was solved by Griess and Lam last year: http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2270 . As it happens, there is already a moonshine for the Thompson group, via the function $j(\tau/3)^{1/3} = q^{-1/9} + 248q^{2/9} + 4124q^{5/9} + \cdots$.  This function is the character of the 3C-twisted module of $V^\natural$, and has a natural $Th$-representation structure.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Borcherds defines $b(\tau)$ this way so that its Borcherds lift gives $E_4$. But the weight 12 discriminant function $\Delta(\tau)$ is the Borcherds lift of $12 \vartheta(\tau)$ so adding $120 \vartheta(\tau)$ gives a weight 1/2 modular form with Borcherds lift $E_4 \Delta^{10}$ and indeed one has the q expansion $E_4 \Delta^{10}=q^{10}-27000 q^{12}+4096000 q^{13} + \cdots$ exhibiting dimensions of Thompson irreps. However this lift only involves the coefficients $b(n^2)$ in the q expansion of $b$ while you see moonshine in $b(n)$ for n square free.

Comment: @S.Carnahan I've added a link to the post for a list of moonshine for other groups, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine#Generalized_Moonshine

Comment: @S.Carnahan Do you see a relation between the moonshine for the Thompson group exhibited in Generalized Moonshine or in the work of Griess and Lam and the apparent moonshine exhibited here for the weight 1/2 modular form $b(\tau)$?

Comment: @JeffHarvey I don't see an obvious connection, but the fact that $j^{1/3} = E_4/\eta^8$ suggests that a relation may exist.

Comment: @S.Carnahan So $j^{1/3}$ is the lift of $b-4 \vartheta(\tau)$ and each term in $b-4 \vartheta(\tau)$ can be written as a sum of (virtual) Thompson irreps.

Comment: @JeffHarvey I think so, although I am rather uncertain about the properties of unlifted coefficients of reverse lifts.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII The other functions for $E_k$, $k=6,8,10,14$ are discussed in Borcherds paper "Automorphic forms on $O_{s+2,2}(R)$ and infinite products". In example 2 of sec. 15 he give the weight $1/2$ form whose lift is $E_6$ and then the required functions for $E_8,E_{10},E_{14}$ follow from the fact that $E_8=E_4^2$, $E_{10}=E_4 E_6$ and $E_{14}= E_4^2 E_6$.

Comment: @JeffHarvey Thanks. By the way, do you know the McKay-Thompson series giving rise to moonshine for the Suzuki group? Excluding the pariahs, Janko groups, and Mathieu groups, this is the only one that seems hard to find and [_not_ in this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine#Generalized_Moonshine). (But I think its $T_{6B}$.)

Comment: The centralizer of 6B is $6.Sz$.  This can be found in Table 2a of the original Conway-Norton paper.

Comment: @S.Carnahan I thought as much. I looked at my copy of the C-N paper and there it was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has since been explored and it appears as though there is an interesting type of moonshine for the Thompson group involving weakly holomorphic weight 1/2 modular forms over $\Gamma_0(N)$ with non-trivial multiplier systems.

To bring out the structure of this moonshine, we can consider the form
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}_3(\tau) &\equiv 2b(\tau) + 240\theta(\tau) = \sum_{\substack{m\geq -3 \\ m\equiv 0,1~\mathrm{mod}~ 4}}c(m)q^m \\
&= 2q^{-3} + 248 + 2\cdot 27000q^4 - 2\cdot 85995q^5 + 2\cdot 1707264 q^8 \\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ - 2\cdot 4096000q^9 + 2\cdot44330496q^{12} + \cdots
\end{align}
where $$\theta(\tau) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}q^{n^2}.$$
Inspection of the character table of Th suggests that we should interpret these first few coefficients as either single, real irreducible representations (with multiplicity 2) or representations of the form $V\oplus \overline{V}$. If we are right in making this association, it might further suggest the existence of a graded module $$W = \bigoplus_{\substack{m\geq -3 \\ m\equiv 0,1 ~\mathrm{mod}~ 4}}^{\infty}W_m$$ where we demand that the module be compatible with the Fourier coefficients of $\mathcal{F}_3$ in the sense that $\dim W_m = |c(m)|$. The alternating signs can be treated by endowing $W$ with a superspace structure. In other words, we can decompose each component into an odd and even part, $W_m = W_m^{(0)} \oplus W_m^{(1)}$. The multiple of $\theta$ in the definition of $\mathcal{F}_3$ was chosen so that each Fourier coefficient could be decomposed into dimensions of irreducibles of the same sign. Then, this super-module is special in that, for $m\geq 0$, $W_m$ has vanishing odd part when $m$ is even and vanishing even part when $m$ is odd. The coefficient of $q^{-3}$ in this sense has the 'wrong sign' in that $W_{-3}$ has vanishing odd part, a feature similar to one observed in Umbral moonshine.

One can take this idea farther and consider McKay-Thompson series as in Monstrous Moonshine, $$\mathcal{F}_{3,[g]}(\tau) = \sum \mathrm{str}_{W_m}(g)q^m$$ where the $\mathrm{str}$ is meant to denote the super trace. It was found that you can naturally identify these McKay-Thompson series with weight half modular forms (obtained via the formalism of Rademacher series) on $\Gamma_0(4\cdot o(g)\cdot m)$, i.e. of level 4 times a multiple of the order of $g$, with non-trivial multiplier system. It was verified that these candidates for the McKay-Thompson series produced a well-defined character for the components $W_m$ for $m\leq 52$. In other words, treating each MT series as a graded character, one can decompose the $W_m$ into irreducible representations of the Thompson group with positive integer multiplicities for $m\leq 52$ and it is conjecture that this holds more generally for all $m$.

As it turns out, this moonshine is also conjectured to enjoy a discriminant property similar to the one observed in Umbral moonshine, and also has a natural connection to Monstrous moonshine in that the Borcherds lift of $b(\tau)-4\theta(\tau)$ is the $T_{3C}$ McKay Thompson series from Monstrous moonshine, as was pointed out in earlier comments.

If you'd like to find out more about this moonshine, all this information was taken from the following paper, written by Jeff Harvey and me: http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.08179

Answer (score 5):

Your observation, which was expanded into a concrete conjecture last year by Harvey and Rayhaun, is now a theorem.  See [M. Griffin,  M. Mertens, "A proof of the Thompson Moonshine conjecture"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1607.03078).

This is not to say that the story is complete.  While we now know that a suitable Thompson module exists, there is still no explicit construction or conceptual (e.g., physical) explanation for its existence.